# How can I express in polar form $z = \frac{1}{(x-3 + iy)^n}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How can I express in polar form

$$z = \frac{1}{(x-3 + iy)^n} $$

$x$, $y$ and $n$ could be any number. $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about the polar form of $1/z$, given the polar form of $z$? Can you find the polar form of $z=(x-3+iy)^n$?

Comment: It would have been easy without the 3.

Comment: Try setting $x'=x-3$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first compute the polar form of $a = x-3+iy$, giving $r = \sqrt {(x-3)^2 + y^2}$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{y}{x-3} \right)$. Writing it as $re^{i \theta}$ and noting that $z = a^{-n}$, we obtain the polar form $r^{-n} e^{-in \theta}$ where $r$ and $\theta$ are the aforementioned constants in terms of $x$ and $y$.